# Is there a way for me to not have to build and source every time I open a new terminal

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, catkin, build, source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

Thank you for your time and consideration!

I'm using ROS melodic on Ubuntu 18.04 distribution and every time I open a new terminal, or even a new tab on a terminal, I have to re-build and re-source my workspace ( "catkin build [package names]" and "source devel/setup.bash"). I used a docker image at university and I didn't have to do this. i'm wondering if there is something that I can do so that once I build my workspace once it's built in all terminals.

Please forgive any terminology misuse, I'm fairly new to ROS and welcome any feedback!

Cheers,

Derek

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/396011/is-there-a-way-for-me-to-not-have-to-build-and-source-every-time-i-open-a-new-terminal/) by [derekboase](https://answers.ros.org/users/96629/derekboase/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-02-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

just run these commands here in your home directory and they should allow you to  not have to retype this command source devel/setup.bash, but remember you will have to run your launch files and packages in your home directory to have effect but i'm not sure you have to type catkin build every time maybe just catkin_make once when there is a new package in your_ws I would also recommend checking out the ROS wiki

```
echo "source <your_ws>/devel/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

---

Originally posted by [bribri123](https://answers.ros.org/users/78090/bribri123/) with karma: 36 on 2022-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [derekboase](https://answers.ros.org/users/96629/derekboase/) on 2022-02-11**:
Absolutely right, worked brilliantly. Thank you!